# video player source update

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to update `source` element of `video` element when user clicks on a link.

Here's the code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="load_src(this);lightbox_open();" data-link="<?php echo $list['file_path']; ?>">
   <?php echo $list['name'];?> <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-right"></i>
</a>
```

Here first I tried loading the source `load_src()` and then call the function to open the video player `lightbox_open()`.

```
function load_src(el) {
  var video_player_el_src = document.getElementById('video_player_frame').getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
  video_player_el_src.setAttribute('src', el.getAttribute('data-link'));
}

function lightbox_open() {
  videojs('video_player_frame').ready(function() {
    lightBoxVideo = this;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.getElementById('light').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';
    lightBoxVideo.play();
  });
}
```

And here's the `video` element block:

```
<div id="light">
  <a class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="lightbox_close();"></a>
    <video id="video_player_frame" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="595" data-setup="{}">
      <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <!--Browser does not support <video> tag -->
      <p class="vjs-no-js">Javascript is disabled.</p>
    </video>
</div>
```

On inspecting the DOM, `source src` attribute gets updated with desired value, but still the player loads the `initial link` "http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4".

If I leave the `src` blank initially, i.e. `<source src="" .. >`, I get `"No compatible source was found for this media"`, which is obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why video is not playing, first time it will play on dynamically changing it will not play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236056/why-video-is-not-playing-first-time-it-will-play-on-dynamically-changing-it-wil)

Answer (score 1):

You are using videojs for video playback so you have to change player's source.

```
var player = videojs('video_player_frame');

var changeLink = document.getElementById('my-change-src-link');
changeLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  player.src(event.target.getAttribute('data-link'));
});
```